# how to create a jobs scheduler in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to create a scheduler jobs in `MySql`, I have a table like a below

```
table : count_sla
================================================================================
ID  |   NAME    | STS|  CUT_OFF |   DATE    |   SLA |
================================================================================
1   |   remon   | 1 |   Y   | 2016-05-03    |   1   |
2   |   dedy    | 1 |   N   | 2016-05-03    |   1   |
3   |   sanjay  | 1 |   Y   | 2016-05-03    |   0   |
4   |   arman   | 2 |   Y   | 2016-05-03    |   0   |
5   |   renaldy | 1 |   Y   | 2016-05-03    |   0   |
6   |   sinta   | 0 |   N   | 2016-05-03    |   0   |
```

I want to change `CUT_OFF` and `SLA` column from this table

- each 5 PM a jobs will run
- a job will update cut_off column from Y to N(each N value will be change into Y)
- a job will be update SLA column(curdate - date column)
- curdate is weekday

Comment: So, what have you tried? Have a go first before you attempt to get someone else to write your own code, or pay someone to do it for you

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a query that does the update per your requirements, that would be something like this:

```
UPDATE count_sla 
   SET 
   CUT_OFF = CASE 
      WHEN CUT_OFF = 'Y' THEN 'N' 
      ELSE 'Y' END, 
   SLA = Now() - DATE;
```

I don't work in MySQL very frequently, but I think the following should do what you want for scheduling that query:

```
CREATE EVENT `evnt_update_count_sla` ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT 'Updates count_sla daily.'
 DO BEGIN    
    UPDATE count_sla 
       SET 
       CUT_OFF = CASE 
          WHEN CUT_OFF = 'Y' THEN 'N' 
          ELSE 'Y' END, 
       SLA = Now() - DATE;
 END;
```

Give it a try, if it isn't 100% correct, it should at least get you in the right direction.

Comment: If you don't have `event_scheduler` `ON` then set it `ON` by this query: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` (forgetting it is an usual case)

Comment: In order to schedule it at 5PM every day : ....`ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2016-05-17 17:00:00'....`